# Context Menu on folder opens in a parent directory

Tags: batch-file, registry, contextmenu

I created a batch file that edits filenames in specific folders.
I would like to add a context menu to it to make it easier to use.
So here is my reg file

```
  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Rename Here]
  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Rename Here\Command]
  @="\"C:\\Rename\\rename.bat\""
```

The problem is that when you right click on a folder the command opens in the parent directory so it renames the parent directory's files.

When i run the bat file manually in any given folder it works fine.

Any help?

Comment: Please post the code in the .bat file.  Most likely the working directory logic is missing or wrong in the batch file.

Comment: yes you were right. I haven't used "cd %1" in batch file and "%1" in registry data entry. thank you for point that out.

Comment: My stupid problem solved. I hope for some deletion of my question without negative votes. Im just noob in batch coding. Thank you

Comment: Don't feel that your questions was stupid.  You asked the question correctly.